# How can i color filtered items in listView after searching in listView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I added a checkbox and there i call a method name Test.
With the test mode i generate random strings and add them to the listView as items. And also keep the items in a List listv.

```
    List<string> listv;
    private void Test()
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
           for (int i = 0; i < random.Next(20,1000); i++)
            {
                string rand = RandomString(200);
                ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Add(rand);
            }
            textBox4.Enabled = true;

            listv = ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>()
                             .Select(item => item.Text)
                             .ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Clear();
            textBox4.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    private static Random random = new Random();
    public static string RandomString(int length)
    {
        const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
          .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Test();
    }
```

Then after generating random items in the listView in textBox4_TextChanged event i'm searching for specific text in the listView:

```
private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            if (textBox4.Text != "")
            {
                int itemsfound = 0;
                ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < listv.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (listv[i].ToLower().Contains(textBox4.Text.ToLower()))
                    {
                        itemsfound++;
                        ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Add(listv[i]);
                        ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items[i].ForeColor = Color.Red;
                        backgroundWorker2.ReportProgress(0, itemsfound);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < listv.Count; i++)
                {
                    ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Add(listv[i]);
                    ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items[i].ForeColor = Color.Black;
                }
                    backgroundWorker2.ReportProgress(0, "0");
            }
        }
```

I filter the search so it will show only the found items.
The problem is that i can't color the found items.
I tried:

```
itemsfound++;
ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Add(listv[i]);
ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items[i].ForeColor = Color.Red;
backgroundWorker2.ReportProgress(0, itemsfound);
```

But getting exception on the line:

```
ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items[i].ForeColor = Color.Red;
```

First time if i type one letter in the textBox4 it will color all the items in red and will show a number in a label of the found items.
The next time when i type another letter(not deleted the first one but added another letter) then i'm getting the exception:

InvalidArgument=Value of '5' is not valid for 'index'.

I loop over listv so in this case the variable 'i' is 5 but in the listView i have only 2 items.

lvnf is the listView and it have 2 items but the value of 'i' is 5.

How can i fix it ?

What i want to do is to filter the results and it was working fine until i tried to color the filtered found items. I want to color in Red each found item/s.

Before i tried to color it in Red the code was:

```
ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Clear();
for (int i = 0; i < listv.Count; i++)
     {
      if (listv[i].ToLower().Contains(textBox4.Text.ToLower()))
          ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Add(listv[i]);
     }
```

But now i want to color the found items.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you're looping over `listv` but only adding to `lvnf` when an item is found.. therefore you can't now use `i` as the index to set the colour, as the indexes are now out of sync.

You need to find the element that you want to target in your `lvnf` by using the current element in `listv`

Try something like this:

```
ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Single(x => x.Text == listv[i].Text).ForeColor = Color.Red;
```

Just draft code, will probably need some tweaking.. but hopefully you get the idea!

Comment: I'm getting error on the Find: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'searchAllSubItems' of 'ListView.ListViewItemCollection.Find(string, bool)'

Comment: See my updated code..
Also your loop can't be working fine, or you wouldn't be trying to access an index that doesn't exist